# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pg_config' on pytest (postgresql installed)

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, pytest

I'm trying to run `pytest` within an Anaconda environment on Mac using a local postgresql DB. I installed postgresql with Homebrew, can confirm that `which pg_config` returns:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config
```

But when running `pytest` I continue to see the error in subprocess.py:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pg_config'
```

The command that is throwing this error seems to be:

```
self = <Popen: returncode: 255 args: ['pg_config', '--bindir']>, args = ['pg_config', '--bindir'], executable = b'pg_config'
preexec_fn = None, close_fds = True, pass_fds = (), cwd = None, env = None, startupinfo = None, creationflags = 0, shell = False
p2cread = -1, p2cwrite = -1, c2pread = 5, c2pwrite = 6, errread = -1, errwrite = -1, restore_signals = True, gid = None, gids = None
uid = None, umask = -1, start_new_session = False
```

Other questions related to `pg_config` seem to be answered by the user not having postgresql installed, linked to their system path, or issues with the `psycopg2` library. As far as I can tell, all of these were installed successfully on my machine. Any thoughts?

**Update with more details:**
I'm using the `pytest-postgresql` extension to set up a Postgresql fixture locally in my test environment, and the error is being thrown when setting up the fixture.

I can run `pg_config` from the directory where I want to run `pytest`:

```
> pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 14.7 (Homebrew)
```

Comment: 1) I doubt that is coming from `pytest` itself, but one of it's extensions. Do you have extensions installed and if so  what are they? 2) From same location where you run `pytest` what happens if you run just the command `pg_config`(without full path)?  **Add information as update to question.**

Comment: Added information. I agree that it's probably not coming from pytest itself, but I suspect that somehow Python or Anaconda is modifying path when trying to run tests such that pg_config is not discoverable

Comment: 1) So is this `> pg_config --version` actually in the Anaconda env? 2) What is the complete command line you use when running `pytest` with `pytest-postgresql`?